# closeness of Sobolev space under multiplication by a periodic function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega=[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]$ and  $H^{p}(\Omega)$ be sobolev space such that $\psi\in H^{p}(\Omega)$. Now if $f$ is a smooth periodic function on $\Omega$ then does $f\psi \in H^{p}(\Omega)$?
I know such result holds in $1D $ that is when $\Omega=[0,2\pi]$.

My attempt:

I tried a particular case when $f=e^{2\pi i k\cdot x}$ (I need this)

Consider $\Vert e^{2\pi i k\cdot x}\psi \Vert _{H^p(\Omega)}^2=\sum_{m\in Z^2}(1+\vert m\vert^2)^p\vert \widehat{e^{2\pi i k\cdot x} \psi}_m \vert^2 =\sum_{m\in Z^2}(1+\vert m\vert^2)^p)\vert \widehat{\psi}_{k+m} \vert^2$

Now how can I show that the series is convergent to prove the claim?

Thanks

Comment: $(1+|m|^2)^p \lesssim_p (1+|k+m|^2)^p + |k|^{2p}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Jose27. If I understand correctly we get $\Vert e^{2\pi i k\cdot x}\psi \Vert_s ^2 \leq C \Vert \psi \Vert_s^2+ \Vert \psi \Vert_{L^2}^2 $. Is it possible to get the estimate like $\Vert e^{2\pi i k\cdot x}\psi \Vert ^2 \leq C \Vert \psi \Vert_s^2 $

Comment: It's correct what you say (though the $L^2$ norm should also have a constant). My previous comment was under the assumption that $p>0$, in which case $\| \psi\|_{L^2}\leq \|\psi\|_p$. The case $p<0$ would need a different argument.

Comment: @PrakashNainwal: Just observe that, with your definition, $\lVert \psi\rVert_2\le \lVert \psi\rVert_s$ (re to "is it possible to get the estimate like...")

Comment: Thanks, @Jose27. I got this one and for me, $p>0$ is given. My question is what if we replace $f_m$ with a smooth periodic function,  say g? \\ What I found is that if s>1 then $\Vert uv\Vert_{H^s(R^2)} \leq \Vert u\Vert_{H^s(R^2)}\Vert v\Vert_{H^s(R^2)}$. Here  I think I can replace $H^s(R^2)$ by $H^s(\Omega)$ and get an inequality $\Vert uv\Vert_{H^s(\Omega)} \leq \Vert u\Vert_{H^s(\Omega)}\Vert v\Vert_{H^s(\Omega)}$.

Comment: @Jose27,  Could you please give me some hint on how did you arrive at the inequality $(1+\vert m\vert^p)\leq C_p[ (1+\vert m+k \vert^2)^p+ \vert k\vert ^{2p}]$ ?. I thought it would simply follow by the triangle inequality but I am stuck.  Thanks

Comment: It is the triangle inequality: $|m|=|m+k-k|\leq |m+k|+|k|$ and use that $a^q+b^q\approx_q (a+b)^q$ for any power $q>0$ and $a,b\geq 0$ (you'll need $q=2,p$). As for your other question; the fact that $H^p$ is an algebra for $p>1$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is indeed true, but you're asking a less subtle question since one of your functions is smooth. In this case you're (probably) bounded on any $H^p$ space. One way I can see of doing it is by treating first the case of $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and then using complex interpolation for noninteger $p$.

Comment: Yes I was doing the same but is $(x+y)^{q}\approx x^{q}+y^{q}$ for any $q\geq 0$ ?. For $0\leq q\leq 1 $ its fine and moreover for $q>1$  using binomial expansion I can see $(x+y)^{q} \geq x^{q}+y^{q}$. Could you give me some hints on how to get the reverse inequality here?